# C program optimization/speed increase

Tags: c, performance, primes

As a beginner, I made a program which finds the number of prime numbers (`prime`) which are not higher than an input natural number (`x`). The program works fine (I think), but I want to make it work faster (for higher numbers). Is it possible, and if yes, how?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x, i, j, flag = 1, prime = 0 ;

    scanf("%d", &x);
    for (i = 2; i <= x; i++) {
        j = 2;
        while (flag == 1 && j < i/2 + 1 ) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                flag = 0;
            }
            j++;
        }
        if (flag == 1) {
            prime++;
        }
        flag = 1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", prime);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1: Find a better algorithm. 2. For your current algorithm, notice that there is only a single even prime. 3. For your current algorithm, note that if you have not found a divisor in the first `sqrt(n)` numbers, `n` is prime.

Comment: Make a list or array of each prime found so far. Only test them as divisors. There is no point in testing if `6` is a divisor if it has already got past `2` and `3` as divisors.

Comment: Look up the Sieve of Eratosthenes.  You could build a somewhat more efficient algorithm based on that.

Comment: @WeatherVane that's nice. I will try to implement this

Comment: As @EOF said, up to `sqrt(candidate)` with big numbers, perhaps add 1 to ensure that you don't miss the actual square root due to rounding errors.

Comment: Not sure if this is enough of a speed boost, but you could replace `if (flag==1){prime++;}` with `prime+=flag;` and you could add `break;` right after `flag=0;`

Comment: Increase compiler optimisation level, and/or look at other optimisations the compiler makes available. Go multi-threaded and use all your CPU cores since problem is CPU-bound. Use `kill` on other users' processes ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm does trial division, which is slow. A better algorithm is the 2000-year old Sieve of Eratosthenes:

```
function primes(n):
    sieve := makeArray(2..n, True)
    for p from 2 to n
        if sieve[p]
            output p # prime
            for i from p*p to n step p
                sieve[i] := False
```

I'll leave it to you to translate to C. If you want to know more, I modestly recommend the essay [*Programming with Prime Numbers*](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays/) at my blog.

Comment: Should `for i from p*p to n step p` be `for i from p+p to n step p`?

Comment: @WillNess yes I see... `p+p` was taken care of by `2`. `p+p+p` was taken care of by `3` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There is one famous prime-number theorem. It states that

```
π(n)≈n/ln(n)
```

But there are certain algorithms for calculating this function. Follow the links:
[PNT](http://primes.utm.edu/howmany.shtml#pnt)

[Computing π(x): The Meissel, Lehmer, Lagarias, Miller, Odlyzko method](http://www.ams.org/mcom/1996-65-213/S0025-5718-96-00674-6/S0025-5718-96-00674-6.pdf)